# Functions in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I am new to Python objects and have a lot of questions. I need to pass a function to my object, and then evaluate the function. The code is similar to this:

```
from sympy import var

class eval:
    def __init__(self, M):
        self.M = M

    def fun(self, x):
        M = self.M
        print M(x)

x = var('x')

ak = eval(x+2)
ak.fun(x)
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
(ipython-input-1-b7ef311bd1f0> in <module)()
     12 
     13 ak = eval(x+2)
---> 14 ak.fun(x)

(ipython-input-1-b7ef311bd1f0) in fun(self, x)
      7     def fun(self, x):
      8         M = self.M
----> 9         print M(x)
     10 
     11 x = var('x')

TypeError: 'Add' object is not callable
```

Comment: what is the error? [edit] your question and include the full traceback.

Comment: Maybe it is because he is adding a string (x) and 2 together

Comment: I'm really confused as to why you're naming your class eval, considering that is a builtin function. Also, what are you trying to do with x = var('x')?

Comment: This code isn't raising any exception for me.

Comment: @Imagine: `x = var("x")` is one way to create a symbolic variable named "x" in the sympy library.

Comment: yes, because, I need pass two function to my objects and then work wich this. But I can pass a function as argument to the object. This is my problem...

Comment: What is your `sympy` version?

Comment: @F.N.B. Yes, you can pass a function as an argument to the object. However, `x+2` returns an `Add` object, which is not a function -- that is why it complains about '.. is not callable'. However I don't know enough about SymPy to know why this is.

Comment: dpkg -l | grep sympy
ii  python-sympy  0.7.1.rc1-3 all Computer Algebra System (CAS) in Python

Comment: So, I have `python-sympy-0.7.2-1` from Arch Community Repo - works perfectly.

Comment: And, there and other form to pass a function and return and other??

Comment: @kampu: [`Add` is callable in sympy-0.7.2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16757074/4279).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian : That's good. My comment was about the evidence though, not about SymPy. Clearly, the `Add` object returned when F.N.B runs it is *not* callable; the exception demonstrates that fact. (the situation is further confused by F.N.B. asking about functions, when Add is not and should not be a function, but should be a callable.). I agree upgrading to 0.7.2 would fix the problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I am new to Python objects...

Having questions is great, but the objects and classes behind SymPy are quite complex and learning the basics of the [Python object model](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) before delving in such a library is strongly encouraged.

There are many issues with the suggested code:

### Purely language related errors

- `eval` is build-in so it is bad style to overwrite it
- using old-style classes

### Using SymPy as if it is some language extension

SymPy does **not** provide new syntax for creating python functions. Especially, `(x+2)(4)` is **not** going to give you `6`. If you want this just write `myfun = lambda _: _+2; fun(4)` without using SymPy.

`x+2` is a SymPy object (`Add(Symbol('x')+Integer(2))`), not some python AST. You can substitute `x` for something else with `(x+2).subs(x,y)` but you can not expect the library to magically know that you have something special in mind for `Symbol('x')` when you write `(x+2)(4)`. You can as well write `blah = Symbol('random_string'); (blah+2)(4)`.

### Minor SymPy errors

`var` is a helper function used to create `Symbol` objects, but it is meant for interactive use in the interpreter. Do not use it in library code because as a side effect it injects global variables in the namespace. Just use `Symbol('x')`.

## Now about `x+2` being callable

In 0.7.2 recursive calling was implemented. What this means is that you can create a SymPy `Expr` tree that contains unevaluated symbolic objects and apply the whole tree on another object, the calls propagating inwards until all unevaluated objects are substituted with evaluated ones. I guess the above description is not clear so here is an example:

You want to create a differential operator object `D` which can do the following:

```
>>> op = g(y)*D # where g is Function and y is Symbol
>>> op(f(x))
g(y)*f(x).diff(x)
```

The way this works is to go down the tree (`Mul(g(y), D)` in this case), skip evaluated symbolic objects and evaluate unevaluated symbolic objects.

Because a lot of SymPy's users start using it before reading about the data model this caused a lot of confusion, so we moved the recursive calling scheme to the `rc` method. In 0.7.3 `(x+2)(4)` will raise errors again.

Comment: +1 for "about x+2 being callable" part. `eval` is not a keyword. It is a builtin name that refers to a builtin function. `Add(Symbol('x'), Integer(2))` looks like (non-Python) AST. Compare it with Python AST for `x + 2`: `BinOp(left=Name(id='x', ctx=Load()), op=Add(), right=Num(n=2))`. `(x + 2)(4)` can be interpreted e.g., `(_ + 2)(4) == 6` where `_` is from [`fn.py`](https://github.com/kachayev/fn.py). It might not make sense in the context of sympy for some other reason but *it can be done without new syntax* (it doesn't mean that it should though).

Comment: Dont confuse eval and exec. Also, the situation is different in python 3.

Comment: @Krastanov thank for your answer and the information, but now I have an other problem. I need pass two fuction to my objects (I can do this witch lambda) and compare if equal, but I can't do this because I can't create a variable 'x' to compare. As I can do?

Answer (score 1):

There is couple issues with this.

- You don't define the class as an object
- You named the function eval which is a reserved word

Try this:

```
class Eval(object):
    def __init__(self,m):
        self.M = m

    def fun(self,x):
        print self.M(x)

x = var('x')
ak = Eval(x+2)
ak.meth(x)
x + 2
```

HTH

Comment: "You don't define the class as an object" Classes are always objects. In 2.x deriving from `object` simply changes what *type* of object it is.

Comment: I don't see how your answer is related to the issue of `x + 2` being callable.

Comment: I'm not sure I see where the OP expected it to be callable?

Answer (score 1):

Your code already can pass a function to the object. Functions are first-class citizens in Python you can pass them as any other object. The issue might be with your `sympy` version. Compare:

```
>>> import sympy
>>> sympy.__version__
'0.7.1.rc1'
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> (x + 2)(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Add' object is not callable
```

And:

```
>>> import sympy
>>> sympy.__version__
'0.7.2'
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> (x + 2)(x)
x + 2
```

i.e., the same code works on `0.7.2` but it fails on `0.7.1rc1` version.

Comment: Please check the docstring before doing what you suggest. You can not use `Symbol` objects as some bizarre lambda syntax.

Comment: @Krastanov: the code reproduces OPs error using a minimal complete code example. It reveals that the class definition, the method call, internal variables assignments in the OPs code are not the issue (as expected) and that *`x + 2` is callable in `0.7.2`* and it is not callable in `0.7.1` (the docstring says as much: `help(x+2)` shows/doesn't show `__call__` attribute depending on the version). I have no idea what semantics `(x + 2)(x)` should or should not have in sympy.

Comment: Calling SymPy objects doesn't do what you would expect and will be disabled in the next SymPy version.